# what's the good way of handling css files edit in symfony2

Tags: css, symfony, assetic

I think I miss something as it goes for edititng CSS in symfony2 project.
I've attached my css file like so:

`{% stylesheets 'bundles/wshcmshtml/css/custom.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
        
    {% endstylesheets %}`

As I've read in documentation when assetis:use_controller is set to true controller should take care of updasting the css file edited in my bundle? But no, I have to run app/console assets:install (assetic:dump does not do anything) with every change.

What do I miss is my workflow with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
app/console assets:install --symlink web
```

in development environment. It will create symbolic links to your assets instead of copying them ann needing to update them for each change.